# Do 2 "different" files on the same server have the same inodes? linux

Tags: linux, centos

Is it possible for two "different" files on the same server to have the same inodes?
In the text of the question declared "different" so please do not follow the shortcut and link

Comment: Your question needs a lot of clarification on what you are asking. Please edit it to give more detail; Include what you have searched for and/or researched. Tell us what is the scenario that caused you to ask this question. Et cetera. In general, an inode is like a Post Office box number: There is only one such number--within the postal code/zone. But the same number may exist in _other_ postal codes/zones, and still be unique. Likewise, the _contents_ of he PO Box are completely unique to that box, even if the box next to it has the same items: If you change them, it does not affect the other

Comment: There is no link or Hardlink

Answer (score 2):

Inodes are unique to the device ("partition") that they are on.

In a single partition, you can have two different *filenames* pointing the same inode, and they will have the same identical content.  Because it is the same file, but with two different names.  This is called a "hard link"

e.g.

```
% echo hello > a
% ln a b
% ls -li a b
2853867 -rw-r--r-- 2 sweh sweh 6 Jul 25 20:20 a
2853867 -rw-r--r-- 2 sweh sweh 6 Jul 25 20:20 b
% cat a
hello
% cat b
hello
```

We can see that "a" and "b" have the same inode and have identical content.

Now if you have different partitions then it's possible to have different files with the same inode number.  That's because the *device* is different.

On my machine `/news` is mounted from a different partition and we can see it has the same inode as `/`

```
% ls -lid / /news
2 dr-xr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Jun 10  2019 //
2 drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 2048 Jul 25 20:12 /news/
```

And we can see it is different using the `stat` command which shows the "Device" value

```
% stat / /news         
  File: '/'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd03h/64771d    Inode: 2           Links: 27
Access: (0555/dr-xr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2021-07-25 06:49:19.766594125 -0400
Modify: 2019-06-10 13:24:11.299255125 -0400
Change: 2019-06-10 13:24:11.299255125 -0400
 Birth: -
  File: '/news'
  Size: 2048            Blocks: 4          IO Block: 2048   directory
Device: fd10h/64784d    Inode: 2           Links: 13
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2021-07-25 20:12:34.000000000 -0400
Modify: 2021-07-25 20:12:32.000000000 -0400
Change: 2021-07-25 20:12:32.000000000 -0400
 Birth: -
```

Comment: It would be more accurate to replace `device` and `partition` above with `filesystem`.